# Creating a program to replace multiple values within a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I posted a question yesterday and shot myself in the foot by accepting an answer that I believed to work, only to find at the end of my project that it had failed, I am truly sorry for this!

To put my program a little bit more clear, I am creating an application using google maps API within android studio, and have been given a database of information such as Latitude, Longitude and areas to link.

this would require a lot of copying and pasting (and I mean a lot!) in order to complete, so I wanted to make a program that basically replaces multiple strings in a single line.
This is the line to be changed:

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LATNUMBER1, LONGNUMBER2)).title("A place"));

Basically, I have a lot of latitude & longtitude & placenames to add into this line, and make duplicates. To do this, I have created 3 listBoxes, each one containing longitude, latitude and place names in order of which they are to be added.

This is the code I currently have:

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "latlong.txt";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.CreateText(path);
        MessageBox.Show("File has been created.");
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter stwr = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            stwr.WriteLine("googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(" + listBox1.Items[i] + ", " + "ii" + ")).title(" + "bbb" + "));");
        }
        stwr.Close();
        string text = File.ReadAllText("latlong.txt");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < listBox2.Items.Count; ii++)
        {

            text = text.Replace("ii", Convert.ToString(listBox2.Items[ii]));
        }
        File.WriteAllText("latlong.txt", text);
    }
}
```

however, the code here:

```
listBox1.Items[i] + ", " + "ii"
```

causes my second set of values to break after the first 10
The first set of values seems to be changing accordingly.

I hope this is clear, would anyone possibly have a solution to this?

Comment: "causes my second set of values to break " - Any errors/exceptions?

Comment: Also, if you have the data already in a database, why not just read directly from there?

Comment: It looks like you are replacing all the "ii" strings in  the entire file in your second loop, so after the first time through, there will be no more replacements

Comment: Sorry, when I meant break, I meant they just appear wrong after the first 10.
And the data is in an excel document, I just found it a little easier to just copy and paste the values into a listBox collection.

Is there any alternatives I could maybe use other than Replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        stwr.WriteLine($"googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng({ listBox1.Items[i] }, { listBox2.Items[j] })).title(\"A place\"));");
    }
}
```

If i understood your problem correctly, this should work.

Edit: Solution that worked

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) 
{
    stwr.WriteLine($"googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng({ listBox1.Items[i] }, { listBox2.Items[i] })).title(\"A place\"));"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately this created thousands of lines in the document for each lat-long.
For example, the first latitude in the list will be displayed with the different longitudes, then once they are all completed, it will go to the second latitude with all of the longitudes:-


googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.79940000000, 31.01680000000)).title("A place"));
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.79940000000, 31.03650000000)).title("A place"));

Comment: Is the count of listbox1 and listbox2 always the same?. If so you can only use one `for` loop: 

 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        stwr.WriteLine($"googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng({ listBox1.Items[i] }, { listBox2.Items[i] })).title(\"A place\"));");
    }

Comment: That's it! Solved it for me! Thanks very much bud!! :D